# build and estimate a time series process

Tags: probability-or-statistics, time-series

I want to generate an EGARCH process. My problem is that I do not see how to create new processes beyond those available.

The process itself is :

$$\epsilon(t) = \sigma(t) \eta(t)$$

$$\log(\sigma(t)^2 ) = w + b\log(\sigma(t-1)^2) + c\eta(t-1) + d \lvert\eta(t-1)\rvert$$

Notice that I want to use `RandomFunction` to generate the simulated values.

Then I'd like to estimate it using the `EstimatedProcess` to estimate the parameters. I want to experiment with false models..

Comment: I forgot to say that "eta(t)" are iid from N(0,1)

Comment: look here http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/mma/gen_timeseries.nb

Comment: To be fair, that notebook on Verbeia.com is very old - probably version 4 vintage. @PlatoManiac - how come you remember what is on my web site better than I do?

Comment: @Verbeia Not my ordinary neural net but all credit goes to proper keyword search in Google! However if you change `AppendRows[a,b]` with Join[a,b,2] and `ZeorMatrix` using `ConstantArray` you will be left with properly using the new version 9 `ARMAProcess` to replace your `ARMAList`. Then we can have a nice post here from you. Looking forward to it!

Comment: @PlatoManiac I'll try to get to it tonight.

Comment: thanks for the information. seems to be a good source. I do not see why the issue is not documented in mathematica.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries - send me an email - the one at my website's About page.

Answer (score 1):

From PlatoManiac's comments:

You could try [Verbeia's notebook](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/mma/gen_timeseries.nb), and replace `AppendRows[a,b]` with `Join[a,b,2]` and `ZeroMatrix` using `ConstantArray` you can use the new version 9 `ARMAProcess` to replace the `ARMAList` in the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can try package I have written for estimating garch process parameters -although it's not finished yet but you can estimate around 10 kinds of garch processes.Just type Ugarch in documentation when you install the package.Any feedback is more than welcome.

https://www.4shared.com/zip/Rb7AXlxYba/garch.html

These are actually  ported R functions package via Rlink.

And here you have example of mathematica code for estimating parameters,this is the fastest code I could write,there are other examples but they are 5-10 times slower...
You will see that the Mathematica optimizer isn't up to task unfortunately so you would have to adjust precision goal for satisfying results...

https://www.4shared.com/file/rHYRzuB8ba/Garch_estimation_mathematica.html